# nm-applet gives errors

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dbus, iwlwifi

`nm-applet` always gives me a hard time when connecting to wireless. I often have to restart it and make several attempts till it connects to a network. Sometimes even restarting the computer doesn't help. This time I ran it from CLI and I got this:

```
** (nm-applet:2950): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-t6ky00XpYq: Connection refused

    ** (nm-applet:2950): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

    (nm-applet:2950): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

    (nm-applet:2950): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 93)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: It seems to arise from this bug: https://github.com/gtimelog/gtimelog/issues/27

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: So from reading comments , I know you restart network-manager and nm-applet to make it work (`sudo service network-manager restart`  ). I suggest you make those commands an autostart entry to be run on every graphical login.  Another alternative - switch from network-manager to `wicd`. It's less pretty but it works. Helped me when my networking went down the drain. Among other things, look into updating your driver and upgrading to 4.0 kernel

Comment: Have you tryed this: nmcli -c -d (the lan ip adr) --force-yes and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

- `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager` service file is provided by `network-manager` package.

  ```
  $ grep -rl NetworkManager /etc/dbus-1/ /usr/share/dbus-1/
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-pptp-service.conf
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-strongswan-service.conf
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-vpnc-service.conf
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-openvpn-service.conf
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-iodine-service.conf
  /etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-openconnect-service.conf
  /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher.service

  $ dpkg -S /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf
  network-manager: /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf
  ```
- Try reinstalling it then reboot

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
  sudo reboot
  ```

Comment: No, didn't help. I restart the nm-applet and network manager each time I want to connect and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has nothing to do with Network Manager.

It is a problem with iwlwifi driver and your adapter.

It was reported that turning power saving feature of this adapter solves the problem. It can be done by running in terminal

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

But this setting will not stay after reboot.

I would turn it off in `iwlwifi` module by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf <<< "options iwlwifi power_save=0"
```

If turning off power save feature in `iwlwifi` module does not help, you can revert it by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

And you can always add `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` to `/etc/rc.local` by running

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and adding `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` before `exit 0` line.

This command will always run on boot.

Another kernel option that may help is `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`.

It can be set by

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

Comment: Power management is already off. I can't remember how I turned it off (which survives reboots) but the output of iwconfig shows that it's off.

Comment: I added another option that may help.

Comment: @Reza And what is Ubuntu version? Did you update packages? It looks like new firmware is installed in May 2015.

Comment: It's Trusty and it's up to date. This problem has survived many updates.

Comment: I did the last command you mentioned and have not had this problem since then. Don't know if the problem is solved or not but the deadline for the bounty was approaching.